# Why can't I connect to my MySQL server that I just installed?

Tags: installation, mysql

I am trying to install mysql 5.1.42 and after running below line

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

I have created `mysqld.sock` and gave permission to it too, but I still get the same error.

Comment: And is `mysqld` running?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL server should create the `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` when it starts, you shouldn't need to create it yourself. The most likely problem is that the MySQL server isn't running. You can check this by running `ps ax | grep mysqld` this will show you the server process if there is one. If it isn't running then start it and give that command another go.